# Datamodeling tools

Tags: datamodel

In early phases of software development projects the conceptual data model is designed. In my experience tools like ERwin and Visio helped with the process. Are there other tools better suited for the job? Is out there any comparison analysis on this sort of tools?

Comment: Here is a list of Case tools http://www.unl.csi.cuny.edu/faqs/software-enginering/tools.html

Comment: Wikipedia list of damodeling tools http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_modeling_tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite like the Quest [Toad Data Modeler](http://www.quest.com/Toad-Data-Modeler/) - so far it seems quite capable, but it's a fraction of the cost of what other "professional grade" ER tools normally cost.

Check it out! I'd say it's worth a good look for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Architect is a nice tool

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the RISE editor: http://www.risetobloome.com/Page_1_S.aspx?ITEM=412

But, a down side is that it can't display relationship strength - ie it shows every relationship as strong and each entity set as strong. Which, isn't a HUGE deal breaker, because I just export to TIFF and edit in Paint.Net (to make the relationship's weak).